# ST_Covers fails on GEOGRAPHY column with GiST index, PostGIS 3.0

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geography-data-type

I'm trying to upgrade to Postgres 12 with PostGIS 3.0. Unfortunately, I can't get my spatial queries to work. There seems to be an issue using `ST_Covers` on a `geography` column with a `GiST` index.

Proof of Concept:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id SERIAL, the_geog GEOGRAPHY);
CREATE INDEX test_geog_idx ON test USING GIST(the_geog);
INSERT INTO test (the_geog) values (
    ST_Buffer(ST_GeogFromText('POINT(-0.1 51.5)'), 10)
);
SELECT id FROM test WHERE ST_Covers(the_geog, ST_GeogFromText('POINT(-0.1 51.5)'));

ERROR:  no spatial operator found for opfamily 19745 strategy 7
```

I imagine this is because `GiST` indexes work in a different way in PostGIS 3.0. How can I solve this issue?

Here is my Postgres version:

```
test=# select version(),postgis_full_version();
                                                   version                                                   |                                                                        postgis_full_version
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 12.1 on x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42), 64-bit | POSTGIS="3.0.0 r17983" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="120" GEOS="3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 " PROJ="6.2.1" LIBXML="2.9.10" LIBJSON="0.13.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.2" WAGYU="0.4.3 (Internal)"
(1 row)
```

Here is the equivalent code with `geometry`:

```
CREATE TABLE geom (id SERIAL, the_geom GEOMETRY(Polygon, 4326));
CREATE INDEX test_geom_idx ON geom USING GIST(the_geom);
INSERT INTO geom (the_geom) values (
    ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-0.1 51.5)'), 10)
);
SELECT id FROM geom WHERE ST_Covers(the_geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-0.1 51.5)',4326));

 id
----
  1
```

EDIT: Here is a snippet with a table named `test1`:

```
sx=# CREATE TABLE test1 (id SERIAL, the_geog GEOGRAPHY);
CREATE TABLE
sx=# CREATE INDEX test1_geog_idx ON test1 USING GIST(the_geog);
CREATE INDEX
sx=# SELECT id FROM test1 WHERE ST_Covers(the_geog, ST_GeogFromText('POINT(-0.1 51.5)'));
ERROR:  no spatial operator found for opfamily 19505 strategy 7
```

Comment: can you add the output from `select version(),postgis_full_version();` using the [edit] button please

Comment: Does the query work without index?

Comment: Yes, the query work without index

Comment: @IanTurton amended, thanks

Comment: What happen if you use `ST_Contains` instead of `ST_Covers` ?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca it works, but I have to cast from `geography` to `geometry` -
`test=# SELECT id FROM test WHERE ST_Contains(the_geog::geometry, ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(-0.1 51.5)'));
 id
----
  1
`

Comment: It is a [bug](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4608)